# É possível atribuir ObjectId() para subcollections no MongoDB?

Tags: banco-de-dados, mongodb

Imaginem a seguinte collection:

```
{
    _id:ObjectId("123456..."),
    user:"João",
    artigos:[
        {
            id: new ObjectId(),
            titulo:"Lorem ispsum.",
            texto:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..."
        }
    ]
}
```

Resumindo: Um usuário pode ter `n` artigos, que por sua vez precisam de alguma forma de identificação para serem achados em uma consulta.

Só que aparentemente o MongoDB não aceita `ObjectId()` em subcollections, eu tentei gerar desta forma e ele dispara um erro informando que não foi possível fazer o *parse* do arquivo JSON. Então minha pergunta é:

**É possível adicionar `ObjectId()` em subcollections? Se não, como eu conseguiria atribuir ids para meus itens dentro desta subcollection?**

Comment: Estamos falando de subdocumentos, certo?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez isto.

Answer (score 1):

## É possível adicionar `ObjectId()` em subcollections (ou melhor dizendo, subdocuments)?

Sim, mas isso não é muito recomendado, porque considerando que a decisão de arquitetura de dados foi de colocar o dado como um subdocumento, supõe-se que a única chave importante é a do documento pai.

Claro que há exceções. Se por exemplo estamos falando de uma pessoa que tenha *n* endereços, e só queremos atualizar um deles, e isto é uma operação recorrente. Aí faz sentido ter.

Estou supondo para o exemplo que a declaração do Schema é mais ou menos assim:

```
Pessoa: {
    enderecos: [
        { _id: ObjectId(), nome: '' },
        ...
    ]
}
```

Fiz um teste com o seu exemplo e funcionou da seguinte forma:

```
db.pessoas.insert({
    "_id": ObjectId(),
    "user": "João",
    "artigos": [
        {
            "_id": ObjectId(),
            "titulo": "Lorem ispsum.",
            "texto": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..."
        }
    ]
})
```

Comment: Mas ai que tá, eu faço isso, mas quando tento adicionar ao banco ele acusa erro, dizendo que esperava uma `string` ou `data`.

Comment: Acho que isso aqui tá errado: `id: new ObjectId()`. Não seria `_id: ObjectId()`?

Comment: Já tentei sem o `new` e também acusa erro. No caso eu já possuo um `ObjectId()` fora desse subdocument (como aparece lá no JSON da minha pergunta), será que é permitido apenas um por document e por isso dispara erro?

Comment: Acho que não. Pode ser apenas um problema sintático. Vou fazer um teste aqui.

Comment: @Kazzkiq Editei minha resposta e coloquei seu teste. Aqui funcionou perfeitamente na shell pura do MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

Essa é uma questão de design de documentos. A grosso modo, há duas rotas a se seguir:

1. incluir o subdocumento (`artigo`) dentro do documento-raiz (`usuario`)
2. linkar/referenciar o documento secundário (`artigo`) no primário (`usuario`)

Como você parece precisar de um identificador para cada artigo, eu sugeriria primeiro tentar encontrar um identificador natural, tipo um número único de arquivamento já existente. Se isso não for possível, você pode gerar qualquer identificador único na hora de salvar o artigo pela primeira vez, tipo um UUID/GUID ou alguma string derivada do título e possivelmente data de publicação (ex: `id_artigo: "2014_08_03_lorem_imsum"`).

Se você preferir um número sequencial para esses artigos, uma forma simples de se conseguir isso é criando uma collection auxiliar `sequencias` que você pode usar para gerar esses números. Eu uso bastante essa técnica com [`findAndModify()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/):

```
var contador = db.sequencias.findAndModify({
    query: {'_id': 'artigos'},
    fields: {'_id': 0, 'seq': 1},
    update: {'$inc': {'seq': 1}},
    new: true,
    upsert: true
});
var novo_num = contador.seq;
```

A alternativa **1** se aplica bem quando os artigos têm apenas um autor/usuário, pois você não duplicará nada:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("123456..."),
    user: "João",
    artigos:[
        {
            id_artigo: "2014_08_03_lorem_impsum",
            data: new Date(2014, 07, 03), 
            titulo: "Lorem ispsum.",
            texto: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..."
        },
        {
            id_artigo: "2013_12_01_so_um_teste",
            data: new Date(2013, 11, 01), 
            titulo: "Só um Teste",
            texto: "Meu primeiro artigo..."
        }

    ]
}
```

Já a alternativa **2** pode ser usada quando existe a possibilidade de um mesmo artigo ser relacionado a mais de um autor/usuário, evitando muita duplicação de dados:

**Artigos**:

```
    {
        _id: "2014_08_03_lorem_impsum",
        data: new Date(2014, 07, 03), 
        titulo: "Lorem ispsum.",
        texto: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..."
    }

    {
        _id: "2013_12_01_so_um_teste",
        data: new Date(2013, 11, 01), 
        titulo: "Só um Teste",
        texto: "Meu primeiro artigo..."
    }
```

**Usuários**:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("123456..."),
    user: "João",
    artigos: ["2013_12_01_so_um_teste", "2014_08_03_lorem_impsum"]
}

{
    _id: ObjectId("987654..."),
    user: "Armando",
    artigos: ["2014_08_03_lorem_impsum"]
}
```